# Elasticsearch.NET (NEST) fails to deserialize my POCO JSON in version 7.x

Tags: json, elasticsearch, serialization

Elasticsearch 7.x for .NET [has a documented breaking change with the internal Utf8 JSON serializer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-breaking-changes.html#_utf8json_for_serialization_2).

Instead of me using the another option -> Newtonsoft's Json.NET serializer, I'm trying to figure out which part of my JSON is breaking the serializer.

- Client nuget: `7.3.1`
- Server: `7.2.0`

Firstly the error *feels* like it's helpful, but I don't think it really is:

```
2019-10-18 17:15:33 ERR Fatal error.
Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: expected:'String Begin Token', actual:'2', at offset:540 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonParsingException: expected:'String Begin Token', actual:'2', at offset:540
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonReader.ReadStringSegmentCore(Byte[]& resultBytes, Int32& resultOffset, Int32& resultLength)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonReader.ReadString()
   at Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver )
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream stream, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.DiagnosticsSerializerProxy.Deserialize[T](Stream stream)
   at Nest.SourceFormatter`1.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)
   at Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver )
   at Nest.ReadAsFormatter`2.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.Formatters.CollectionFormatterBase`4.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)
   at Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver )
   at Nest.ReadAsFormatter`2.Deserialize(JsonReader& reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver)

... etc ...
```

So at character `540`, something is bad.

So I *think* I have the json which came back. I *think* because I asked a collegue to use Fiddler and give me the payload result. I can't paste the full payload anywhere because it contains sensitive stuff but this is the part of code at line 540

[image]

There's no '2' there.

So what about the Json? Here's a nicely formatted screenshot of the json, with the custom results hidden:

[image]

and finally, the poco section, for the section *I think* is erroring (but I'm not sure):

```
        [Keyword(Index = false)]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [Keyword]
        public string Suburb { get; set; }

        [Keyword]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Keyword]
        public string StateCode { get; set; }

        [Keyword]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Keyword]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        [GeoPoint]
        public GeoLocation LatLong { get; set; }
```

So:

- I'm not sure how to grab the exact json which is parsed by NEST. Is it the json I grabbed, which can be confirmed by the snippet I provided?
- Is there a way I can manually create a unit test + use the internal Utf8 serializer with NEST to load my json if I save this JSON payload to a file in order to debug this further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is with enums. Out ES DB has some small subset of documents with a `number/int` value while our POCO has a `string` value. The string value is the string representation of our enums, while the int value was the previous int representation of the enums.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string statusType { get; set }
}
```

To figure out what the error is/was, I needed to do the following:

- Clone ES repo and put a breakpoint in ES's `JsonSerializer` `Deserialize<T>` method because SourceLink is **not enabled** on the ES nuget packages (as of the time of this posting).
- Update the method to convert the byte array to a string, so I can see what the JSON payload is, before it tries to get deserialized into our POCO.
- Step through the code, to finally hit the breakpoint and see what the json payload is.

So the error message is in respect to the json *segment* of my document. Not the *entire* json ES payload. In the above examplei have 5 'hits' (document segments) so the `Deserialize` was getting hit 1x per document segment. When it hit the segment with the `int` values (which should have been `string` value) it then crashed. So I can now see what the error at `char 540` is and viola....

```
  "statusType": 2,
```

which is bad. is should be:

```
  "statusType": "available",
```

So - problem identified.